# Как задать диапазон рандомизации rand()?

Tags: c++, случайные-числа

Проблема: не умею задавать диапазон рандомизации от 2003 к 2020. 
Мой код:

```
struct Date
{
    int day = rand() % 29;
    int month = rand() % 12;
    int year = rand() % 2020+2003;
    void Print()
    {
        cout << "Date of B:" << day << "." << month << "." << year << endl;
    }
};
```

Но у меня выходит какая-то каша, помогите сделать так, чтобы дата рандомилась, например, от 2003 года к 2020 году.

Comment: `(rand() % (2020 - 2003 + 1)) + 2003;` а вообще используйте <random>

Comment: https://ideone.com/s1ZowH

Answer (score 3):

Только тогда уж рандомизируйте и месяцы-дни правильно :)

```
int month = rand() % 12 + 1; // Январь - 1...
int year = rand() % 18 + 2003;  // От 2003 до 2003 + 17
const int md[] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

int D = md[month-1];
if (month == 2 && year%4 == 0) ++D;

int day = rand() % D + 1;
```

Хотя через юлианскую дату и нормальный `<random>` было бы равномернее; а так, например, будет небольшой перекос - поскольку в феврале меньше дней, а на них будет приходиться то же количество выпаданий, что и на любой другой месяц...

Comment: Плюс возможный дополнительный небольшой перекос из-за операции `%` (в зависимости от значения RAND_MAX)

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan А для того `<random>` и упомянут :)

Answer (score 3):

В C++20 (равномерное распределение по дням между from/to включительно):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <random>

using namespace std::chrono;

int main() {
  auto from = sys_days{January/1/2003};
  auto to = sys_days{December/31/2020};

  std::random_device dev;
  std::mt19937 rng(dev());
  std::uniform_int_distribution<std::mt19937::result_type> dist(0, (to - from).count());

  year_month_day random_date = from + days{dist(rng)};

  std::cout << static_cast<int>(random_date.year()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(random_date.month()) << std::endl;
  std::cout << static_cast<unsigned>(random_date.day()) << std::endl;
}
```

[Рабочий пример](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CLGlD3DHTc1nBEnb)